# The wedge product

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

I have seen the wedge-product as being defined in differential geometry in the definition of a differential form or p-form. Now in the course we have proven the basic properties of this product and how to take the differential.

Now when we apply this to the differentiation of a function in on a curved manifold, we make the following change in the integral $\int dx^n\rightarrow\int dx^0\wedge dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^{n-1}$.

I don't see how the wedge product is related to the volume element, I was hoping that you guys might be able to clear that up for me ?

Second, I already asked around about this, the wedge product is said to be the generalisation of the cross vector product and the 3D volume element to higher dimensions. I was woundering of anyone could explain that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right place to start is with determinants.  The determinant of a 2 by 2 matrix can be thought of geometrically as the (signed) area of the parallelogram formed by the column vectors.  The exterior product is a way of formalizing this intuition.  The expression $dx^0\wedge dx^1\wedge...\wedge dx^{n-1}$ is by definition the volume element.  The wedge product is a "generalisation" of cross product only in the sense that both involve the area of the parallelogram in one way or the other.  Otherwise there are significant differences between them; thus, the exterior product is associative but the cross product is not.  There is a good introduction to these ideas [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the link was extremely helpful !